# What is the CGI show I'm thinking of that seems eerily similar to the Voltron episode of Rick and Morty?

Tags: story-identification, rick-and-morty, voltron

Recently, I remembered that as a child in the 90s, I watched a CGI show that revolved around a team of pilots that controlled some kind of animal robots. This show would have aired on YTV in Canada in the late 90s - maybe licensed from Cartoon Network/Toonami?

In the show, they had some underground base that they used to activate these vehicles and go fight evil. A major plot point of this series was that at one point, either the base or robots were destroyed and the pilots were no longer able to fight evil. As a kid, I remember this being *traumatizing* - I was invested in this series and I was watching the heroes getting systematically dismantled by the bad guys. This might have been some kind of finale as I don't remember watching the show again after that.

I did some minor googling based off of what I remembered but couldn't come up with any results. It left my mind until I watched the *Rick and Morty* episode *Gotron Jerrysis Rickvangelion*.

The entire *Rick and Morty* episode seems to mirror this show exactly as I remember it - animal robots stored in an underground lair. Specifically, the "robot suit up scene" at approximately 3:20 seems to be *exactly* what I remember. I'm almost positive that this CGI series I'm trying to remember also had one of the animals inside a volcano. The bright primary colors also seem very familiar.

I've since learned that this Rick and Morty show is parodying the anime series *Voltron*. However, I definitely didn't watch this anime show growing up, and I distinctly remember these robots being terrible CGI animations.

Watching the *Rick and Morty* episode makes me certain that this CGI show exists and helped inspire the visualizations, or that the CGI show entirely ripped off the imagery from Voltron. What is the CGI *Voltron*-like show I'm thinking of?

Answer (score 5):

After doing some more research, I'm certain that this is *Voltron: The Third Dimension*. I found [a trailer for the show](https://youtu.be/nN-PSupY6cQ) which demonstrates the CGI animations and showcases a "robot suit up scene" where the pilots control lion robots. One of them is, in fact, inside a volcano!

Reading through [TV Tropes for the series](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WesternAnimation/VoltronTheThirdDimension), it seems like the first season ends with the cliffhanger I remember of the robots being destroyed:

> Cliffhanger: Season 1 ends with Zarkon achieving his takeover of the Galactic Alliance, the Lions still destroyed, Arus under threat from Lotor, and the rest of the Voltron Force on the run.